# Prevent unwanted auto-complete suggestion completions from transforming `IT.` into `await...`

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

In the following GIF, typing <kbd>I</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> turns my lambda into an async/await. What I am trying to typing is `It.IsAny<string>()`.

[image]

It seems like the suggestion commits when I press the period key. How can I prevent that behavior while still maintain the ability to view and select suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false` fixes this for me by making the commit happen on <kbd>tab</kbd> - that's better.

[This Reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/mkrz0a/commit_character_configuration/) indicates that commit characters are language specific. That implies that <kbd>.</kbd> is a commit character in C#.